Разработка пк игр на Unity
Какие книги на русском языке для обучения разработке игр на Unity с использованием C# для начинающих с нуля можете посоветовать?

(но кто-нибудь обновите там ↑ ответ, а то 2017 год был довольно давно)

@andreymal а по Unity особо ничего не поменялось с тех пор: Framework 4.8, да Standard 2.0. Ну по движку всякие RTX/DLSS добавились, но это на программирование особо не влияет. Вот будет CoreCLR, там будет хорошая пачка нового.

Автору советую сначала в голом C# поковыряться и ООП выучить, и только потом начать Unity щупать.

Не думаю, что на русском найдётся много книг. Так что какие достанете, те и читайте, выбор невелик.
